# Implicit conversion operator with generic type

Tags: c#, generics, implicit-conversion

I am trying to write generic method, which should parse `JToken` to concrete type, by using implicit conversion operator.
I've got my implicit operator like this:

```cs
public static implicit operator CategoryDto(JToken token)
{
    var result = new CategoryDto
    {
         //Mapping here
    };
```

And method with generic type:

```cs
public static T ParseResult<T>(this JToken response, string relationship) where T : class, new()
{
     //Implicit operator is triggered, fields were mapped as expected 
     CategoryDto concreteResult = response["value"];
 
     //Line below doesn't trigger my custom conversion, even when T is CategoryDto      
     T result = response["value"];

     return result;
}
```

I would expect my `result` variable will be mapped according to implicit operator - but nothing happens, even if I pass `CategoryDto` as a `T` parameter - `T` is `CategoryDto` with default values.

I can not understand why this snippet doesn't work (probably due to lack of knowledge about polymorphism/generic types).

Is it related with compile/runtime behavior for generic types?

Comment: Are you using .NET 7?

Comment: _"Line below doesn't trigger my custom conversion"_ -  what do you mean here? It does not compile?

Comment: A generic method has only one implementation for all reference types (and one per each value type, but that's not relevant here). As `T` is not known to be a `CategoryDto`, the compiler cannot insert a call to your conversion operator. This is not how you should be doing JSON deserialization in the first place, that's what `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` is for.

Comment: I am using .NET6,

@Guru Stron - sorry for inaccurate description - it doesn't compile with message "Cannot impicitly convert 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' to 'T'.

Comment: You can't do it with .NET 6. .NET 7 introduces abstract static interface members, which allows you to constrain `T` to an interface that implements the implicit conversion from `JToken` to `T`. But Jeroen Mostert makes a good point: use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` instead, and implement a custom converter.

Comment: Thank You very much for all the answers. I’ll go with custom converter then!

Answer (score 2):

Compiler will not allow to compile this because this is not type-safe - `T` can be any type which matches the constraints and there is no way to guarantee that explicit conversion from `T` exists (pre-.NET 7 at least).

Usually you will want to rely on the actual json parsing (possibly using some custom converter), for example:

```
public static T ParseResult<T>(this JToken response, string relationship) where T : class, new() 
    => response["value"].ToObject<T>();
```

If you really want to leverage the implicit conversion (though I would recommend against it) you can do something like:

```
public static T ParseResult<T>(JToken response, string relationship) where T : class, new()
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(CategoryDto))
        return (T)(object)(CategoryDto)response["value"];
    return response["value"].ToObject<T>();
}
```

Since .NET 7 you can use [static abstract interface members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/static-virtual-interface-members):

```cs
public interface IImplicitlyConvertableFromJToken<T> where T : IImplicitlyConvertableFromJToken<T>
{
    static abstract implicit operator T(JToken token);
}

class CategoryDto : IImplicitlyConvertableFromJToken<CategoryDto>
{
    public static implicit operator CategoryDto(JToken token)
    {
        var result = new CategoryDto
        {
            //Mapping here
        };
        return result;
    }
}

public static T ParseResult<T>(JToken response, string relationship) 
    where T : class, IImplicitlyConvertableFromJToken<T>, new() 
        => response["value"];
```

But again - I strongly recommend to look into using standard parsing from json approaches.

Comment: That `(T)(object)(CategoryDto)` is just unspeakably ugly, yet also the shortest way of actually writing this. While the `(T) (object)` pattern isn't new, I don't think I've ever seen *three* casts in a row in legitimate code (for some value of "legitimate").

Comment: @JeroenMostert Totally agree. I think I used just the `(T) (object)` pattern itself  around one time in production code in my whole career =)